# Person I'm Trying to Contact Display PGP key but not their email

Tags: encryption, email

I am trying to contact someone who displays their PGP key on their website in their 'Contact' section. But they do not state their email there. How can I email them?

Answer (score 3):

The email is usually included, but not required, in the key itself. Import the key, or use some software to inspect it, to get the email, if its there.

Otherwise, as Sjoerd said, you probably need to search a keyserver.

Answer (score 1):

You can search a [keyserver](https://pgp.mit.edu/) for the key's fingerprint.